Approximation of product of quotients
Fix some real positive number $v,w$ with $v>w>0$, consider
$$f_{v,w}(n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{v-w+k}{v+k}=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(1-\frac{w}{v+k}).$$
By plotting the graph wrt $n>0$ for some fixed $v,w$, I think it is true that $\lim_{n\to +\infty} f_{v,w}(n)=0$. (I believe I can do this by myself, so this is not my main question) Besides that, I wonder whether there is some approximation of $f_{v,w}(n)$ that can reveal how fast $f_{v,w}$ decreases.
That is, I want to find some $g_{v,w}(n)$, which has a simpler form, that satisfies $f_{v,w}(n) = \Theta(g_{v,w}(n))?$

Using Pochhammer symbols $$f_{v,w}(n)=\prod_{k=0}^{n-1} \frac{v-w+k}{v+k}=\frac{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}  (v-w+k}{\prod_{k=0}^{n-1}(v+k)  }=\frac{(v-w) (v-w+1)_{n-1}}{v (v+1)_{n-1} }$$
Going to the gamma function
$$f_{v,w}(n)=\frac{\Gamma (v)}{\Gamma (v-w)}\,\,\color{blue}{\frac{\Gamma (n+v-w)}{\Gamma (n+v)}}$$
For the blue piece, take logarithms, use twice Stirling approximation
$$\log \left(\frac{\Gamma (n+v-w)}{\Gamma (n+v)}\right)=-w \log (n)+\frac{w (w-2 v+1)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)$$
Re-exponentiate
$$\frac{\Gamma (n+v-w)}{\Gamma (n+v)}=n^{-w} \left(1+\frac{w (w-2 v+1)}{2n}+O\left(\frac{1}{n^2}\right)\right)$$
$$f_{v,w}(n)\sim\frac{\Gamma (v)}{\Gamma (v-w)\,n^w}$$
